# Fork() and waiting for child processes to finish using wait()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have a program that copies the content of files into a Destination.

I am struggling with implementation of an option `-j`
so the program makes the copies in child processes. The numeric argument to -j must be greater than or equal to 2.

- With `-j 2`, there are a total of **two processes** at once: **1 orchestrator** and **1 that does the copies**.
- With `-j 3`, there are a total of **three processes** at once: **1 orchestrator** and **2 doing the copies**.
- With `-j 10`, there are a total of **ten processes** at once: **1 orchestrator** and **9 that perform the copies**.
- If there are more than **j - 1 files** to copy, the orchestrator **waits** for the end of a copy beore starting the next copy process.

So to answer to the question : **when should the wait be done, at the second fork?**

Answer : **After the forks() and comes back to life as soon as one of its kids dies. The parent should be able to see the number of kids he has and as soon as it drops below the limit, he forks a new kid**

`./prog -j 3 t/a/a   t/a/b   t/a/c   t/b`, we want to copy content of a and b into `t/b/`

---

```
       |   |                 |      |   |                   |
       |   |                 |      |   |                   |
       |   |                 |      |   |                   |
       |   |----t/a/a->t/b/a-|      |   |                   |
       |                            |   |                   |
        -----t/a/b -> t/b/c---------|----                   |
                                    ------t/a/c -> t/b/c-----
```

What I tried:

```
//PSEUDO CODE
    while (nbFiles > 0)
    { // Loop through files
        for (i = 0; i < nbprocess; i++)//.... loop of the process.
            {
                pid = fork();
                        wait(&status);
                if (pid == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // do the task
        }
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("erreur de fork");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I had already forgotten the question but I was not clear enough, I apologize I am new to this platform,
feel free to ask for further clarification.

Comment: What is you actual question here?

Comment: The diagrams show you writing two different files to `t/b/c`.

Comment: If you do `wait` after the `fork` like in your pseudo-code, then you do `wait` on the parent and on the child. And even if you do it on the parent, you would wait and then launch the next child. So, what is the point of child processes when you are executing them sequentially?

Comment: In order to take advantage of the parallelism, you need to fork all children one after the other and store the child pids in an array. Then after launching the children, you use `waitpid` for every pid of the children. Use `waitpid` because with `waitpid ` you can control which child you are waiting for

Comment: It doesn’t really matter which child you wait for, just that one terminates. You only need to keep track of how many children are currently spawned, so `wait()` will suffice. The “orchestrator” is the parent process. Only child process copy files. So the parent only needs to make sure there are as many child processes as possible until it runs out of files to copy.

Comment: @Barmar i m so sorry i just edited the diagrams, i had some mistakes there

Answer (score 0):

If you do `wait` after the `fork` like in your pseudo-code, then you do `wait` on the parent and on the child.

On child process this would probably lead to undefined behaviour (the man page does not mention this) as the child process would not have at this point any child to wait for.

And on the parent side, you wait for the child and then launch the next child. So you are executing them sequentially, so why even bother with the forks.

In order to take advantage of the parallelism, you need to fork all children one after the other and store the child pids in an array. Then after launching the children, you use `waitpid` for every pid of the children. Use `waitpid` because with `waitpid` you can control which child you are waiting for

```c
//PSEUDO CODE
    while (nbFiles > 0)
    { // Loop through files

        pid_t children[nbprocess]; 
        // or malloc(nbprocess * sizeof *children) for 
        // very large nbprocess, but don't forget to do free if
        // you use it
        for (i = 0; i < nbprocess; i++)//.... loop of the process.
        {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                // CHILD process, do the task
                // end with exit
                exit(0); // or whatever status
            } else if (pid > 0) {
                // PARENT aka orchestrator
                children[i] = pid;
            } else {
                perror("erreur de fork");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        int wstatus;
        for (i = 0; i < nbprocess; i++)//.... loop of the process.
        {
            // wait for the children one at a time
            waitpid(children[i], &wstatus, 0);

            int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(wstatus);
            printf("The child #%d exited with status %d", i, exit_status);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you could do the waiting like this, when you don't care about the
order or the waiting:

```c
        int wstatus;
        for (i = 0; i < nbprocess; i++)//.... loop of the process.
        {
            // wait for the children one at a time
            waitpid(-1, &wstatus, 0);

            int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(wstatus);
            printf("A child exited with status %d", exit_status);
        }
```

As Dúthomhas mentions in the comments, the parent is the *orchestrator*.